# Bolt-CMS Using extensions in page?

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I read this from a recent answer to a question:

> After enabling the extension, just use {{ twitterfeed() }} in your templates.

But, what if I only want say a contact form on one page? Putting the tag in the page's text field doesn't work. And putting it in the template would have it available on all the pages using that template. Do I have to duplicate a template to use only for the contact page? If not where do I put the contact form tag?

I went to Bolt's extension page, selected "how to use extensions" from the menu, and got this message:

> No proper name for a page in the docs. Bye!

Perhaps someone at Bolt could fix the URL?

I would like to know why none of the extensions I want to use are not working. I am clearly missing a vital piece of info.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> After enabling the extension, just use {{ twitterfeed() }} in your templates.

The [Twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html) `{{ twitterfeed() }}` belongs (generally speaking) in a Twig template file.  You can use Twig in record fields, but that requires setting `allowtwig: true` for that Contenttype field.

> But, what if I only want say a contact form on one page?

There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest way is to make a copy of your sites template file for the page's Contenttype and select that template for the 'Contact' record.  The default ['pages' Contenttype](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/master/app/config/contenttypes.yml.dist#L33) that comes with Bolt has a `templateselect` field type that enables this.

> No proper name for a page in the docs. Bye!

Fixed!  Thanks for pointing it out.